# Datasource connection doesn't work in JBoss

Tags: sql-server, jboss, connection, datasource

I'm trying to do a datasource connection on JBoos, but without success.

I saw this tutorial to do my connection: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/DataSource+configuration

after the error : "ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration" I tried others tutorials, but all of them I get the same error : "ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration"

I search, but I don't find the error.

error:

```
17:51:35,411 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015956: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:141) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:266) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:155) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Duplicate attribute 'pool-name'. at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [349,146]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructWfcException(StreamScanner.java:606)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:479)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:464)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.AttributeCollector.throwDupAttr(AttributeCollector.java:1143)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.AttributeCollector.resolveNamespaces(AttributeCollector.java:997)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.InputElementStack.resolveAndValidateElement(InputElementStack.java:498)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleStartElem(BasicStreamReader.java:2942)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2802)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1050)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextTag(BasicStreamReader.java:1125)
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.nextTag(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:152) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ParseUtils.nextElement(ParseUtils.java:52) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ParseUtils.nextElement(ParseUtils.java:68) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readServerElement_1_1(StandaloneXml.java:343) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:100) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:133) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        ... 3 more
```

Standalone.xml:

```
<datasources>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/PNDS" pool-name="DS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://CX:1433;databaseName=DS_des</connection-url>
        <driver>sqlserver</driver>
        <pool>
            <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
            <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
            <prefill>true</prefill>
        </pool>
        <security>
            <user-name>us</user-name>
            <password>mo</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>

    <driver name="sqlserver" module="com.microsoft">
        <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.sqljdbc4</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
</datasources>
```

module:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.microsoft.sqlserver.sqljdbc4">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="sqljdbc4-4.0.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

Answer (score 0):

After googling a bit it seems this error is reported as a TOC bug in several sites:

```
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Duplicate attribute 'pool-name'. at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [349,146]
```

(i.e: https://bobswift.atlassian.net/browse/TBL-387, https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-23412)